# Python retreived data from list in the same element - check name of 2 elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

How do I get 2 elements to be checked if there are inside an element in python? The idea is that for my data collection I need only the lists that are associated whit some titles.

Or is there a way to make this for the first element in the title list if the title corresponds to access the second list?

Ex:

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="title-selection"></div>
   <div class="list-selection"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. Have you tried using an XHTML Parser?

Comment: Well, thank you for answering so shortly. in that section div I have 2 other divs that return 2 lists. And if the first list has a specific title name I want to make it go further and continue whit the data retrieved from the second list that is the list section.

Comment: @user8408080 awww.... I saw what you did there... hmm.. I'll try